# Rust: Mutable references to each element of a tuple possible at the same time

Tags: rust

Below code compiles without any issues:

```
fn main() {
    let mut w = (107, 109);
    let w0 = &mut w.0;
    let w1 = &mut w.1;
    *w0 = 110;
    *w1 = 111;
    println!("{}", w0);
    println!("{}", w1);
    println!("{:?}", w);
}
```

But the following doesn't compile where w is now an array:

```
fn main() {
    let mut w = [107, 109];
    let w0 = &mut w[0];
    let w1 = &mut w[1];
    *w0 = 110;
    *w1 = 111;
    println!("{}", w0);
    println!("{}", w1);
    println!("{:?}", w);
}
```

Why is it the case that it works with tuples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is it the case that it works with tuples?

A tuple is an anonymous structure, even if the fields are named by their position. So the compiler understands that `w.0` and `w.1` don't overlap and it's able to [split the borrow](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/borrow-splitting.html).

Arrays however are [indexed](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html#impl-Index%3CI%3E-for-%5BT;+N%5D), they are opaque to the compiler, for which `w[0]` and `w[1]` may well be the same location.